# How to keep leftover pizza tasting fresh

Tags: food, temperature, storage

Whenever I order pizza, I always have some leftovers. I'll usually have them in the next day or two, but they never taste as good. I don't know if it's how I store the pizza (in aluminum foil in the fridge) or how I reheat it (in a microwave), but they never have the crispiness that I want (it's too soggy). **How can I store and reheat pizza so that it tastes like I just bought it?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Storage

Get an airtight plastic container and line it with paper towels. Place a piece of pizza on the paper towels, then place some more paper towels on top. If you have more than one piece of pizza, repeat until all of the pieces are stored. If you plan to eat the pizza in the next 24 hours, store it in the fridge. Any time longer than that, store it in the freezer.

### Reheating

Before you reheat, let the pizza warm up to room temperature/

#### Oven (best when you have a lot of pizza)

Preheat oven to 400<sup>o</sup>. Place the pizza on a baking sheet and bake it for 15 minutes. The pizza is good if the cheese is bubbly and crispy brown in spots.

#### Toaster Oven (best for one or two slices)

Preheat to 400<sup>o</sup>. Place the pizza in the oven and bake for 10 minutes. The cheese should look bubbly and gooey.

#### Microwave (quickest, but least effective)

Put not only the pizza (on a microwave safe plate is usually the best) in the microwave, but also put a half-filled glass of water. The water will prevent the heatwaves from going deep inside the pizza, making it only heat the crust and cheese. Reheat for 30 seconds.

Source: [WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Store-and-Reheat-Pizza)

Comment: +1 for using a toaster oven. I usually reheat the pizza for 30 seconds or so in the microwave, then run it through a "toast" cycle in the toaster oven to burn off the moisture and make it crispy again. It even works for delivery pizza that I've frozen, I just microwave it longer to thaw it.

Comment: I only ever use the microwave to reheat pizza if its still fresh (aka hasn't been refrigerated yet) to remelt the cheese. Otherwise it just gets soggy and chewy. The toaster oven is a good way to reheat refrigerated leftover and get it tasting like fresh.